# Creating scoped expressions in R to clean intermediate variables

Tags: r, scope, evaluation

Which is the appropriate way to create scoped expressions in R, that is encapsulated commands whose variables are eliminated after evaluations.

The way I'm using right now involve using `with()`:

```
> with(data.frame(), {foo <- 5; bar <- 6; foo + bar})
[1] 11
> foo
Error: object 'foo' not found
```

But it's clearly an hack.

(BTW, if you pass `c()` instead of a `data.frame()` to `with()`, the new variables actually end up in the parent environment; don't know why)

Comment: I don't think this is possible in R. I do not know what your exact use-case is, but usually one would go about refactoring the code into function to avoid creating tons of temporary variables. like `x <- function() {foo <- 5; bar <- 6; foo + bar};
x()`

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but you can create what Javascript calls "IIFE"s eg `(function(x){y=x+2;return(y)})(1)` doesn't leave a `y` hanging aorund.

Comment: yes spacedman, that's what I needed. (function() {a <- 5; b <- 6; a + b})() works! Write it as answer please

Comment: The proposed duplicate is not relevant. The OP of that question wants a local scope in functions not influenced by global variables. I want to evaluate inline one-time expressions on the fly without leaving stuff in memory

Comment: I don't know the motivation of using an ugly Javascript idiom in R. It would seem to warrant the same remark that the construct in the question warrants: "it's clearly a hack."

Comment: So there's no "official" way? only hacks?

Comment: `with(new.env(), {foo <- 5; bar <- 6; foo + bar})` as an alternative to data.frame()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`local({foo <- 5; bar <- 6; foo + bar})`

or

`local({foo <- 5
  bar <- 6
  foo + bar})`

from `?local` (my emphasis)

> local evaluates an expression in a local environment. It is equivalent to evalq except that its default argument creates a new, empty environment. This is useful to create anonymous recursive functions and as **a kind of limited namespace feature since variables defined in the environment are not visible from the outside**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match.call`, `expression` and `eval`:

```
> no_effect <- function(...){
+   .call <- match.call()
+   .call[[1]] <- as.symbol("expression")
+   expr <- eval(.call)
+   
+   eval(expr, list(), enclos = parent.frame())
+ }
> 
> no_effect({foo <- 5; bar <- 6; foo + bar})
[1] 11
> foo
Error: object 'foo' not found
```

The solution is close to what you already wrote.

Comment: Nice solution too!